# Virtualization - Linux KVM-QEMU host Windows VM guest, how to access data drive

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, samba, kvm-virtualization

What is the best way to share a Data partition on a Linux KVM-QEMU host with a Windows VM guest?

I could use Samba networking and connect to the drive as a network share but I was hoping there might be a simpler way.

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 3):

I would use KVM's (and QEMU's) internal Samba networking (which you are referring to, I guess). It works just fine and is pretty easy to setup, just pass `-net smb=/somewhere/data`.

Comment: Not sure about 'KVM's internal Samba networking' I was referring to installing Samba server on the same host machine, is that the same thing?  Using virt-manager so how do I pass these parameters?

Comment: No. KVM/QEMU has the ability to provide a Samba share to the guest via the `-net smb` option. You do need a installed Samba daemon on the host, but you do not have to configure it -- KVM will do this for you. No idea how that integrates into virt-manager, though.

Comment: So how do I use the -net smb option to get a Samba share in the Windows VM guest without using virt-manager?  Is this the same thing as Filesystem passthrough or is that something different.

Comment: `man kvm` says:
    smb=dir[,smbserver=addr]
               When using the user mode network stack, activate a built-in SMB server so that Windows OSes can access to the host files in dir transparently. The IP
               address of the SMB server can be set to addr. By default the 4th IP in the guest network is used, i.e. x.x.x.4.
               Then dir can be accessed in \smbserver\qemu.
so you bassically have to call `kvm ... -net smb=/mnt/data` and can access it in the guest via smb under `\\10.0.2.4\qemu`

Comment: Not making much progress with this at the moment.  Under CentOS 6.3 the virsh command is present as is virt-manager but I don't seem to have either kvm, qemu, or qemu-kvm commands available.

Comment: @NickC It's been more than a year, but I had this issue, and stefanha at virt@irc.oftc.net (`virt-manager` IRC channel) [linked me to his blog post](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.vmsplice.net%2F2011%2F04%2Fhow-to-pass-qemu-command-line-options.html&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNE8L7Bf5x9wrjJHo79L4eBqffxoSA) that shows how to pass `qemu-system` (`kvm` binary's been deprecated since) arguments to `libvirt`-based guests.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188301/how-to-set-up-samba-sharing-with-libvirtd